# checking if a child exists as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I would like to check if a child exists and if it does remove it. If not do something else...I also plan to do the check for many more children....

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown3);

function onKeyDown3(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if( event.keyCode == Keyboard.BACK )
    {
        if (over.stage){
        event.preventDefault();
        removeChild(over);
        gotoAndPlay(350, "Scene 1");
        }else {
        event.preventDefault();
        gotoAndPlay(346, "Scene 1");        
        }

    }
}
```

I tried that, but it doesn't work. But I think it shows basically what I want to do but with a lot more else if's for other children. "Over" is just a movie clip

The error:

```
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/setChildIndex()
    at Bike_safety_fla::MainTimeline/onKeyDown1()[Bike_safety_fla.MainTimeline::frame146:17]
    at runtime::ContentPlayer/sendKeyUpDown()
    at runtime::SimulatedMobileDeviceContentPlayer/onBack()
```

Comment: Elaborate on "it doesn't work"? What error do you get? If its a null reference exception it's cause you aren't nulling the reference to `over` after you remove it as a child. But there are different ways to solve that depending on what you are trying to do

Comment: Ahh, I do get that error, provide a solution to fix please. Check question for 100% of error

Comment: `if (this.contains(over)) { removeChild(over); }` if you mean remove `over` from the display list.

Comment: That error doesn't seem to be coming from the posted code. Unless there is an implicit `setChildIndex` that I'm not seeing.

Comment: I've never used setChildIndex. Looking for it, but it's nowhere.

Comment: Your error is from `onKeyDown1`, but your cited code is `onKeyDown3`.

Comment: Ahh, I have found it. Eyes have been playing tricks. What should I do to fix it? Not sure why it happens as it's on frame 146....this only goes to 346.

Comment: I removed the code that was causing the error...it some what works now....it removes the child. But if there is no child it does nothing. If I change the frame from 346 to anything else it does however. Any ideas?

Comment: If I change the if I change the frame from 350 to 346 it works....so it's something with the else

Answer (score 4):

Use [contains()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#contains%28%29) to test if `over` is on the display list.

From DisplayObjectContainer   documentation:

> Determines whether the specified display object is a child of the
>   DisplayObjectContainer instance or the instance itself. The search
>   includes the entire display list including this DisplayObjectContainer
>   instance. Grandchildren, great-grandchildren, and so on each return
>   true.

Implemented as:

```
if (this.contains(over))
{
    removeChild(over);
    gotoAndPlay(350, "Scene 1");
}
else
{
    gotoAndPlay(346, "Scene 1");        
}
```

Comment: Perhaps your "over" is null already? You're checking "over.stage" while not checking if "over" is null.

Comment: I am having issues with the else statement, it executes regardless. Is there a way I could do something like...if child does not exist (but I want it to work with multiple children) So like if over,under do not exist etc

Comment: If anyone happens to run into this, this was exactly what I was looking for for a different solution. During my code I was adding children to an array and then later on I had a clear function that iterated through the array and removed all items. However sometime in the middle of the game there was a chance that some of the items already got removed and so by checking if this.contains(), I could do it properly. Thanks!